# Unexpected token '{' when passing prop to vue component from blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I need to pass a variable from a blade to a vue component, usually I am able to do something like

```html
<vue-component :the-prop="{{ blah }}" />
```

when passing prop values. However in this case I'm trying to pass a value from `$_SESSION`, and I am getting an invalid token error and am not sure how to get around it.

I've tried:

```html
<vue-component :the-prop="{{ $_SESSION['data'] }}" />
```

and

```html
<vue-component :the-prop="{{ session('data') }}" />
```

and it seems never to even get to the "session" portion and gives me an error:

```
Invalid expression: unexpected token '{'
```

the code works fine if i hard-code an id like so:

```html
<vue-component :the-prop="3" />
```

and typing out `v-bind:the-prop` makes no difference

Comment: View the resulting source. What's showing up in there?

Comment: Maybe this solves the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54049103/2412335

Comment: @ceejayoz the component does not render at all

Comment: I'm not asking about its rendering. I'm asking about the HTML source that Laravel winds up putting out.

Comment: This is because `session('data')` contains a JSON string but you're trying to bind an object, just `json_decode(session('data'))`

Comment: @ceejayoz right, the html just shows the whole page without the vue component

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I tried that as well but I still get `unexpected token '{'` it seems the issue is with the {{ }} not with the session_data (that may be a problem too but the code never gets there to tell me if there are errors with it)

Comment: Have you tried using the `@json` blade directive?  `:the-prop='@json(session("data"))'`  This is what I use to pass objects to Vue.

Comment: Also, are you sure you are in a `.blade.php` file?  What happens if you dump the session variable just before the component declaration, i.e. `{{ dd(session('data')) }}`.

Comment: "Unexpected token" is a JS error, so for you to get it, *something* must be output where the component should be in the HTML. What is the HTML being generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a component, prefixing an attribute with a colon means you want it handled directly by PHP, [as described in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#passing-data-to-components). So instead of this:

```html
<vue-component :the-prop="{{ $_SESSION['data'] }}" />
```

Try this:

```html
<vue-component :the-prop="$_SESSION['data']" />
```

Or, even better, this:

```html
<vue-component :the-prop="session('data')" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this from a blade template file, you should remove the colon so that the value is not binded. Blade itself should plug in the variable value from your {{  }} syntax, so there is no binding needed on the vue side of things.

Comment: when I do it that way, the component renders however the session variable is not extrapolated it just prints as a string instead of showing what the variable actually is

Comment: as in it prints out `{{ $_SESSION('data') }}` instead of `3` for clarification